# Method for solving an Ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying ODE's and I met this equation:
$4x{u}''(x)+(2+x){u}'(x)-\lambda u(x)=0,\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $.
The solution says that this equation is satisfied if we choose  $\lambda =-\frac{1}{2}$ and   $4{u}'(x)+u(x)=0$. So the solution will be: $u(x)=e^{-\frac{x}{4}}$. We are searching for non trivial solutions. I cannot understand what method we use to solve this equation.

Comment: Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: https://users.math.msu.edu/users/yan/847ch3.pdf  Dylan it's the problem in page 2

Answer (score 1):

If you let $u=e^{-x/4} v$, the equation becomes
$$8 x v''-2 (x-2) v'-(2 \lambda +1) v=0$$ If, now, using $v=\sqrt x\,t$
$$4 x t''-(x-6) t'-(\lambda +1) t=0$$ So $\lambda=-1$ gives a "simple" answer since the, reducing the order, the equation becomes separable and you can get at least, $t'$.

What I think is that you forgot to tell which are the boundary conditions.

Comment: users.math.msu.edu/users/yan/847ch3.pdf  PAGE 2

Comment: @JimArt. OK, I see better now. In fact, they are "forcing" the solution using these specific conditions . But, as the problem was initially set, the differential equation has solutions for any value of $\lambda$.